# How to set cookie in deno websocket

Tags: nginx, websocket, digital-ocean, kubernetes-ingress, deno

How do you set the cookie in a websocket connection? I want to do this because I am using nginx ingress session affinity to correlate a user's session with a specific pod. But this request is being made in a serverless function (i.e. deno). I have read the following:

- [Websocket connection with authorization header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64934740/websocket-connection-with-authorization-header)
- [HTTP headers in Websockets client API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361173/http-headers-in-websockets-client-api/4361358#4361358)

But unfortunately the proposed solutions don't seem to work for me. Specifically, setting the affinity token in a url parameter or having it set automatically by the browser. For more context here's the part of my code that makes this call:

```js
const wsUrl = `wss://${this.username}:${this.password}@${this.host}/api/${this.id}`
this.logger.info(`Connecting to WebSocket URL: ${wsUrl}`);
this._ws = new StandardWebSocketClient(wsUrl);
```

The configuration of the relevant ingress controller is as follows:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-kernel-gateway
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    cert-manager.io/issuer: letsencrypt-nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-type: basic
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-secret: basic-auth
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-realm: 'Authentication Required - wovenmind'
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/affinity: "cookie"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-name: "cookie-affinity"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-hash: "sha1"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/affinity-mode: persistent
spec:
  rules:
    - host: host.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: service
                port:
                  number: 8888
  ingressClassName: nginx
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - host.com
    secretName: letsencrypt-private-key
```

The problem is that it doesn't seem there's a way to configure the ingress container to use the affinity token from the params, and there is no way (that I am aware of) to set the headers automatically / globally like you might see in a browser.

Am I mistaken, or is it not possible to pass cookies through a websocket connection in deno?

Comment: Note that I found the following which seems interesting. But obviously if there's a better option I'd rather take that. https://deno.land/x/custom_socket@1.1.0

Answer (score 0):

See the following for a good overview of the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77060459/13752922

See also a possibly useful utility from Deno: WebSocketStream.

1. https://developer.chrome.com/articles/websocketstream/
2. https://deno.land/api@v1.38.3?s=WebSocketStream&unstable=

The WebSocketStream has a signature similar to `new WebSocketStream(url, { headers })` but I'm not sure if it's applicable to your use case.

Finally, if you're using a kubernetes cluster, you should consider creating a proxy service between the current implementation of the websocket and the current server. What I mean is that you create a service (Ingress + Service) that accepts some format of the `Sec-WebSocket-Protocol` header (which is configurable in standard websocket like `new WebSocket(url, [...protocols])`) such that you are able to derive the desired headers and then it proxies the caller with the target service. For example, consider the following Sec-WebSocket-Protocol header: ["some-protocol", "cookie|{cookie value}"] which then on the proxy it checks for this header and then sets the header on the subsequent request to the target service. Keep in mind that "some-protocol" is required, you'll need to also include it in your return even if you do nothing with the protocol.